# Contador de palavras otimizado em C

Tags: c

Estou tentando entender um exemplo de código em C para contar palavras (do livro Programming Pearls). Mas estou com dúvida em alguns trechos do código (talvez eu não tenha digitado corretamente):

- `nodeptr bin[NHASH];` Isso declara uma array do tipo `nodeptr` com o
  tamanho de 29989?
- `for i = [0, NHASH]` Este comando existe em C? É apenas uma forma
  abreviada de um loop `for(;;)`?

Código completo:

```
typedef struct node *nodeptr;
typedef struct node {
   char *word;
   int count;
   nodeptr next;
} node;

#define NHASH 29989
#define MULT 31
nodeptr bin[NHASH];

unsigned int hash(char *p){
   unsigned int h = 0
   for ( ; *p; p++)
      h = MULT * h + *p

   return h % NHASH
}

int main(void){
   for i = [0, NHASH]
      bin[i] = NULL

   while scanf("%s", buf) != EOF
      incword(buf)

      for i = [0, NHASH]
         for (p = bin[i]; p != NULL; p = p->next)
            print p->word, p->count

   return 0
}

void incword(char *s){
   h = hash(s)

   for (p = bin[h]; p != NULL; p = p->next)
      if strcmp(s, p->word) == 0
         (p->count)++

   return

   p = malloc(sizeof(hashnode))
   p->count = 1
   p->word = malloc(strlen(s)+1)
   strcpy(p->word, s)
   p->next = bin[h]
   bin[h] = p 
}
```

Comment: Tenho muito mais interesse em estrutura de dados agora, além de não ter tido muitas aulas na faculdade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> nodeptr bin[NHASH]; Isso declara uma array do tipo nodeptr com o tamanho de 29989?

Correto.

> for i = [0, NHASH] Este comando existe em C? É apenas uma forma
> abreviada de um loop for(;;)?

Realmente isso não faz o menor sentido em C e acredito que em qualquer linguagem, pelo menos nenhuma que eu conheça.

`for(;;)` é um *loop* infinito.

Na verdade o código todo parece ter problemas básicos de sintaxe. Só alguns exemplos:

```
while scanf("%s", buf) != EOF // Falta parênteses aqui.

for (p = bin[h]; p != NULL; p = p->next) //p não está declarado em lugar algum.

return // Daqui pra frente nada será executado.

p = malloc(sizeof(hashnode))
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Syntax/Wrong.c).

Falta ponto e vírgula final em praticamente todas as linhas.

Comment: Ao invés de digitar, eu peguei olhei o fonte:

`int main()
{ int i;
 nodeptr p;
 char buf[100];
 for (i = 0; i < NHASH; i++)
  bin[i] = NULL;
 while (scanf("%s", buf) != EOF)
  incword(buf);
 for (i = 0; i < NHASH; i++)
  for (p = bin[i]; p != NULL; p = p->next)
   printf("%s %d\n", p->word, p->count);
 return 0;
}`

Comment: Vou refazer essa função em JS